# How to configure a Linux Lamp server and a godaddy domain name?

Tags: dns, http-status-code-404, domain-name

1) I have a website I made using a lamp server on a linux desktop and have forwarded my router to allow me to connect using the routers ip.  So if i go to the browser and type http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX my website shows up perfectly fine.

2) I have registered a domain name with godaddy

3) i created an A-record that points to the same ip as my website

4) if you do an nslookup on my domain name it gives the ip i want

The problem is that when i go to the domain name i get a google 404 error not found

any help or suggestions would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after waiting 2 days it finally resolved guess I'm just the one lucky person that had to wait the entire 48 hours for it to resolve.  If you come across this error i would first wait the 48 hours before you get impatient like i did haha